# Exception while executing insert query having some special characters in the value

Tags: npgsql

I have a column with character varying datatype. We are using `Npgsql -Version 4.0.4` and `PostgreSQL version 11.3`

```
String value = "Shaun Hollis_002\\Top of Personal Folders\002\\� 35% Off 
Harlem Globetrotters - 3 Events in Denver!.msg";

        try
        {


            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            sb.AppendLine("Insert INTo tbltemptest1 (c_value) values(@value);");

            using (NpgsqlConnection con = new NpgsqlConnection(DBConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(sb.ToString(), con))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@value", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar).Value = value;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

Performing the insert query is throwing an exception

> invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x00

Answer (score 0):

The error pretty much say it: PostgreSQL refuses to accept strings with 0x00 (the null character) inside them. You will need to clean up your input before sending it to PostgreSQL.